# Android cursor cycle through column

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to change each value in a column called "date". What this basically entails is cycling through the column and changing each entry to the latest day difference. The problem is that my code keeps changing everything to the same value. So basically even though "days left" for each entry should be different, it all comes down to the same number. This is my code.

```
String[] projection = { HabitTable.COLUMN_ENDDATE, HabitTable.COLUMN_ID };
        //Get end date from database
        Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(MyHabitContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null, null, null);
        //Store end date in array
        if(mCursor != null){
            do{
                endDate = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HabitTable.COLUMN_ENDDATE));

                //Whole bunch of code to calculate days left
                String[] eDate = endDate.split("-");
                int eDay = Integer.parseInt(eDate[0]);
                int eMonth = Integer.parseInt(eDate[1]);
                eMonth--;
                int eYear = Integer.parseInt(eDate[2]);
                Calendar cNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
                cEnd.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, eDay);
                cEnd.set(Calendar.MONTH, eMonth);
                cEnd.set(Calendar.YEAR, eYear);
                long diff = cEnd.getTimeInMillis() - cNow.getTimeInMillis();
                long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                if(days <= 0){
                    days = 0;
                }

                String y = String.valueOf(days);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(HabitTable.COLUMN_DAYSLEFT, y);
                getContentResolver().update(MyHabitContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,values, null, null);
            }while(mCursor.moveToNext());
        }mCursor.close();
```

Is there any big mistake I've made I haven't caught?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what u r missing is the ID to update

try like this

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(HabitTable.COLUMN_DAYSLEFT, y);
 // Apply condition here
 String where = HabitTable.COLUMN_ID+"="+mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HabitTable.COLUMN_ID));
 getContentResolver().update(MyHabitContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,values, where , null);
```

[here](http://www.9android.net/content-provider/) is a good example ..

Comment: could you show me your answer before your previous edit? I was just in the middle of reading it and didn't get to finish and I think it might help me to understand a bit too

Comment: please check here http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/how-to-use-getcontentresolver-update-t44066.html